# while loop never becoming false for function that generates a public and private key pair

Tags: python, function, private-key, public-key

I am writing a program in python that generates a public and private key pair. My code so far looks like this

```
def gcd(a,b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
        return(a)

    pass

def inverse(a, b):  # use extended euclidean algorithm to find inverse
    x1, x2, x3 = 1, 0, a
    y1, y2, y3 = 0, 1, b
    while y3 != 0:
        d = x3 // y3
        y1, y2, y3, x1, x2, x3 = (x1 - d * y1), (x2 - d * y2), (x3 - d * y3), y1, y2, y3

    return x1 % d

    pass

def generate_key(a, b):

    n = a * b
    p = (a-1) * (b-1)
    e = random.randrange(1,p)
    g = gcd(e, p)

    while g != 1:
        e = randrange(1,p)
        g = gcd(e,p)


    d=inverse(e,p)

    return ((e,n), (d,n))

    pass
```

But when I run a test code it never completes and goes on running until I manually stop it. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: could it be that you forgot a random infront of the randrange in the while loop? So in the while loop replace `e = randrange(1,p)` with  `e =random.randrange(1,p)`

Comment: still goes on forever. I actually deleted the random before to see if it fixed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the implementation of gcd, the return shouldn't be inside the while because it will run only once and return, you have to do something like this:

```
def gcd(a,b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b

    return(a)
```

I don't know if there are any more problems because you didn't provide de inverse function

Comment: I just updated the question to include the inverse my mistake

Comment: I have run with that function and the adjust in gcd and it works properly, can you see if this is what you expected? @DillonHector